# MIPS: sign extend in I-Type commands

Tags: computer-architecture, number-formats

My lecturer told me that when I use an arithmetic I-Type command (ADDI,SUBI etc.) , the IMM field gets sign extended, and when I use a logic I-Type command (ORI,ANDI etc.) , the IMM field is just bits.

He also said that if the IMM field contains a negative number, it is represented in 2's complement.

Let's say I have a command, and two binary numbers X Y, so that X's 2's complement representation looks exactly like Y in regular representation.

Note: X is negative and not the same as Y.

Given a question in which I should say what is the value in the IMM field in an arithmetic I-Type command, how do I know if it's X or Y?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking: How do if the IMM field contains X or Y?

Answer (score 2):

In an arithmetic I-type command, the IMM-field is treated as a signed number. So if the first bit is 1, the number will be treated as negative (X in your terms.) The number Y is simply too large to be used as argument of an arithmetic I-type command.

Comment: So if the number is sign extended, the sign bit in only the lsb?

Comment: It's the MSB, not the LSB. But yes, sign extending means just setting all new bits to the value of the previous MSB.

Comment: MSB, okay. But I still don't get it: Say the IMM in a certain command is 1111111111111000, how do I know if it's a negative number represented in 2's complement or a regular positive binary number?

Comment: You know it from the type of instruction (i.e. the opcode). If it's an arithmetic instruction, the number is interpreted as negative; if it's a logic instruction, the number is interpreted as positive.

Comment: If it's an arithmetic instruction how do you know if it's negative? And if it is, how do you know where the sign extention starts?

Comment: As always with 2's complement, the number is negative, if and only if its MSB is 1. Sign extension will simply take this bit and repeat it to the left as often as needed.

Comment: Ok so if i have 111111111111000 how do i know where does the sign extension start?

Comment: Sign extension is done, when your (in this case 15 bit) IMM is put into the (32 bit) ALU. So if 111111111111000 is the IMM of an arithmetic command, it will be put in the ALU as 11111111111111111 111111111111000. If it is the IMM of a logic command, it will be put in the ALU as 00000000000000000 111111111111000. (And if yuor IMM is the 16-bit value 0111111111111000, it will be put in the ALU as 0000000000000000 0111111111111000 in both caes.)